# Unexplainable determination coëfficiënt

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a series of [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r96amt7pr4cf86k/Spreadsheet%20co%C3%B6rdinates.csv) (more specific, they are coördinates of a package attached to the end of a mini level-luffing crane. The "flightpath" is linear and horizontal.)

Now when I plot the data:

[Plot http://puu.sh/5LvHS.png](http://puu.sh/5LvHS.png)

Notice the labels on both the X and Y axis. If you would take orthonormal axes, one would not be able to see this is NOT a straight line. 
YET, when I perform linear regression, the coefficient of determination is only 0.2133. Isn't this impossible? Shouldn't it be something like 0.999?

Note that I performed the statistical analysis (bot regression and determination of the statistical parameters) via Excel and via Geogebra.

If this is a normal R squared, then perhaps one of you could answer the following:

The reason I need R squared, is because I need a quantitative parameter which shows me how 'well' the flight path approximates a straight line. I thought R squared was a good idea but apparently not because in my situation it does not show what is a good flight path and what is not. (For clarification, this is a near PERFECT flight path).

Comment: Why do you expect it to be so high? I don't think offhand that it is an unreasonable value for it to take. Specifically: R squared doesn't provide verification that the right form of regression was used. And doesn't it get closer to 1 with better fit?

Comment: For alternatives, maybe RMS deviation?

Answer (score 1):

yes, i think i see why you are puzzled, and your reaction is very honest.

the thing about a correlation coefficient is that (as used here) it measures the extent to which one variable can predict the variation in the second variable. so you can see why it is not that high. it is *scaled* to take into account the standard deviation of the second variable, so even if the error was reduced by a factor of ten, the $R^2$ value would not change.

therefore your conclusion is absolutely correct, that this is not the appropriate measure of accuracy that you want. a better measure would be the standard deviation of the error divided by the length of the path.

however the correlation is not useless. as you can see the errors are not randomly distributed along the flight path, but rather form almost exactly one cycle of a sinusoidal-type fluctuation. this might direct the designer's attention to some factor in the situation whose unwanted interference could be reduced.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What is the standard deviation of the error?

Comment: standard deviation is a measure of deviation from the mean. if you have a set of $n$ values $x_i$ then the mean $m = \frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$  given this, the error (deviation from the mean) of the observation $x_i$ is $x_i - m$ however if you just add all the errors, then by definition of the mean this will be zero, the _ve terms will ncancel the -ve terms. so you make them all positive by squaring them. you then find the mean of these squared deviations, and finally]. to make this independent of scale, take the square root.

Comment: if you have software to compute regression, it will undoubtedly also be able to do the simpler calculation of standard deviation. this is an absolutely fundamental property of a distribution. the regression coefficient factors out the standard deviations of each of the two variables, and calculates a similar value called covariance, and again a square root is taken. this scale-independence is why $r$ is always numerically less than 1.

Comment: Thank you. [image](http://puu.sh/5LyC2.png)


On that image, what would be the standard deviation I need?

Comment: sorry my first comment got a bit garbled and i can't edit it. i will correct it and repost:

Comment: REVISED 
standard deviation is a measure of deviation from the mean. if you have a set of n values x_i then the mean $m=\frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n$ given this, the error (deviation from the mean) of the observation $x_i$ is $x_i−m$ however if you just add all the errors, then by definition of the mean, this sum will be zero, as the +ve deviations will cancel the -ve ones. so you make them all positive by squaring them, then find the mean of these squared deviations, and finally, to make this independent of scale, take the square root.

Comment: Sy is the s.d. of the error in flight path

Comment: OK, thank you. Why would you want to take the difference with the mean instead of the residu? Or is it that in this case you could consider the $y_{mean}$ as the regression $y=y_{mean}$, because the flight path is horizontal?

Comment: yes. btw the SE software is complaining that this exchange is too long, but i think you have the essence.